# How do I configure Ctrl-W to delete a word in Command Palette and File Picker?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to delete words with Ctrl-W in all 'dialog boxes' in VS Code.
Ideally, it would be great to be able to add other Emacs-like shortcuts generally acceptable in Linux.

Note, I am not interested in applying this in the code editor (I use the vim plugin there :))

I tried the following:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+w",
        "command": "deleteWordLeft",
        "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
    },
```

But it delete word in the current editor.